# UNC in a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I need to solve the UNC error when Calling a batch file.

I have a file called Control.bat . When I call it i call it with an input which is a UNC-catalog.

fx

```
control.bat \\MY_UNC_SEARCHWAY\test\test
```

How can I make this work? I know that I can use pushd to get to it but that wont help me in this, will it?

My script:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set i=0
set testname=%1
REM list files sorted to date and get the sizes of the latest two of them:
for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir /o-d /b %1') do (
echo Kontroll av fil: %%f
set /a i+=1
if !i! gtr 2 goto :out
set size!i!=%%~zf
 set name!i!=%%~nxf
)
:out 
echo Totalt antal filer i katalogen: %i%
echo Fil1: %name1% = %size1%
echo Fil2: %name2% = %size2%
set /a diff=size2-size1
echo Difference: %diff%
```

Comment: You have a typo error in `%1%` that sould be `%1`.  If this is not in your real code, how does it not work?

Comment: oh I see the error. It worked with that error anyway. well the error is that it cant run it with an unc path as inparameter so I dont really know how to solve it.

Comment: `it can't run` does not explain the difference between the expected behaviour of the script and the actual behaviour. What is the difference? Why do you think it does not work?

Comment: The problem lays in the `for /f` command treats _strings_ so `%%~zf` returns size of file `%%~f`. If it is not fully qualified, it returns size of that (non-existing) file name in the current directory, i.e. supposedly `0` or something like `null`. So use either `dir` with `/s` switch or (maybe better) `pushd %testname%` before `for` loop and `popd` after it...

Comment: @JosefZ, this should solve the problem. Better post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem lays in this fact: the `~` [argument or parameter modifier](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) in a `for` command or `.bat` script treats *strings* (i.e. *not* file *objects*) and **does not care** about a *file* existence.

So `%%~zf` returns size of file `%%~f`. If it is not **fully** qualified, it returns the file size of that (non-existing?) file name in the current directory (or uses [this rules if qualified partially or relatively](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx#fully_qualified_vs._relative_paths)), i.e. `%%~zf` returns supposedly empty string (or something like `null` which expands to an empty string in `set "size!i!=%%~zf"`).

Hence, use either `for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir /o-d /b /s %1') do (` with `/s` switch or (maybe better)

```
pushd %testname%
for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir /o-d /b') do (
  echo Kontroll av fil: %%f
  set /a i+=1
  if !i! gtr 2 goto :out
  set size!i!=%%~zf
  set name!i!=%%~nxf
)
popd
```

Further resource: `pushd` and [UNC Network paths](http://ss64.com/nt/pushd.html)